# What is "asset_version" role in html

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, assets

so, i was checking some web page source code and I've noticed this at the end of some CSS links and images :
**?asset_version=**
and also this **?v=**
What is their role ?? sorry for the English.
Thanks

Comment: CSS files can be cached, each new release or update to the css, people can append a new version number - and the browser will treat this as a new file, and makes sure that the browser downloads the latest css - https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/. Also see Cache busting.

Comment: so when I add **?v=** the browser don't fetch cache ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are used for `cache busting`. Most web severs will tell a browser to hold onto various resources like image, css and javascript files so that on the users next visit they do not have to be downloaded. By appending a version control value they can force the browser to download the newer versions, otherwise the browser might not download the newer files because it still has a version that's within the time frame it was told to hold onto the same file for the domain.

The process might go a little something like this:

1. Hold onto my CSS file for 180 days, `<link href="path/to/css/style.css">`.
2. 30 days later I update my CSS file. Browser will want to use the one you already gave it as it's valid for another 150 days. But you want it to use the newer version so you use a cache busting technique. So you might do this `<link href="path/to/css/style.css?v=09252015">`.

The browser uses the complete path to identify resources from a domain. Changing the query string value effectively makes the browser think it's a different file.

You will also come across people cache busting in the actual file name also.

`<link href="path/to/css/style-09252015.css">`

Comment: Thanks , I get it now. 1 more question, is **?asset_version=** work the same as **?v=**

Comment: Yes. It's just a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Query strings contain key/value pairs. The key can be anything you want. The primary point of using the query string of a URL path is to change it so the browser thinks it's receiving a different file even though you haven't changed its name. Is this evaluate to true `if ( 'style.css?v=1' === 'style.css?version=1' )`? No. Neither does this `if ( 'style.css?v=1' === 'style.css?v=11' )`. They're different strings/paths. You could change the key every time if you wanted, `?v=1` to `?bird=1` to `?car=1` and it would work.

Answer (score 2):

This tends to be a solid way to force browsers to fetch a new version of a file if you modify it. Often, browsers will not respect the `cache-control` header specified, or you may not have the option to configure that (for example, a limited shared hosting environment). In that case you simply modify the URL by incrementing a version number, which convinces the browser it's a new version, even though it will likely return the same file.

as far as the browser is concerned, `resources/css/application.css?v=1` and `resources/css/application.css?v=2` are different files, even if the css file itself is totally unaware and uncaring of the trailing query parameters.